# Export scraped data to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, scrapy

Can someone please explain to me how to export the scraped data from this script to a csv through a python script? It seems that I am successfully scraping the data through the output I am seeing, but I am not sure how to put this into a csv efficiently.  Thanks.

```
import scrapy
import scrapy.crawler as crawler

class RedditbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redditbot'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']
    output = 'output.csv'  

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'a': 'b'}
        #Extracting the content using css selectors
        titles = response.css('.title.may-blank::text').extract()
        votes = response.css('.score.unvoted::text').extract()
        times = response.css('time::attr(title)').extract()
        comments = response.css('.comments::text').extract()

        #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(titles,votes,times,comments):
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'title' : item[0],
                'vote' : item[1],
                'created_at' : item[2],
                'comments' : item[3],
            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info

def run_crawler(spider_cls):
    """
    spider_cls: Scrapy Spider class
    settings: Scrapy settings
    returns: Twisted Deferred
    """
    runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
    return runner.crawl(spider_cls)     # return Deferred


def test_scrapy_crawler():
    deferred = run_crawler(RedditbotSpider)

    @deferred.addCallback
    def success(results):
        """
        After crawler completes, this function will execute.
        Do your assertions in this function.
        """

    @deferred.addErrback
    def error(failure):
        raise failure.value

    return deferred

test_scrapy_crawler()
```

Comment: Alright, I updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can include the [Feed Exporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-storage-backends) configuration on the settings before running the spider. So for your code try changing:

```
runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
```

with

```
runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner({
    'FEED_URI': 'output_file.csv',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
})
```

The output items should be inside the `output_file.csv` file in the same directory you run this script.

Comment: Thanks @eLRuLL.  I added that to my code, and it definately outputs a csv to my current working directory.  But it is blank for some reason. Any thoughts?  Also, I can only open the file in "read only" mode. Is there a way to shut this feature off without exiting out of my program?

Comment: I would say it depends on the OS you are using. Maybe your spider is not returning any items? (`zip(titles,votes,times,comments)` could be empty). Try outputting a dummy item inside the first line of `parse`, like `yield {'a': 'b'}` and check that it got populated inside the exported file. After that, you'll just have to debug your code better.

Comment: @J.Dykstra please remember to accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: I must not be scraping anything then.  Because my output is blank, event after I put: yield {'a': 'b'}.  Not sure what is going on.